# Show that any function space $F = \{f | f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ is finite dimensional iff the set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is finite

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, real-numbers

I have been posed the following question, and have some insight but largely am not sure how to approach it.

Show that the monomials $1, x, x^2, ..., x^n$ are linearly independent as elements of $C([0,1])$. Conclude that $C([0,1])$ is not finite dimensional. More generally, show that any function space $F = \{f | f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ is finite dimensional if and only if the set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is finite. [Hint: use the fundamental theorem of algebra!]

Breaking the questions into parts:

- Show that the monomials $1, x, x^2, ..., x^n$ are linearly independent as elements of $C([0,1])$.

This part I don't really need help on, and I mostly just included it here for completeness.

- Conclude that $C([0,1])$ is not finite dimensional

This part I have an idea about, but I'm not sure how valid it is. I know that $C[0,1]$ is the set of functions continuous on the interval $[0,1]$. Logically, it makes sense to me that you could find polynomial functions of every degree that are included in this interval, but I'm not sure how I'd go about formally proving this. Would it suffice to give one example of a continuous function of infinite degree that exists in $C[0,1]$? If so, would $sin^{2n}(x)$ where n is an infinitely large number be an example?

- More generally, show that any function space $F = \{f | f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ is finite dimensional if and only if the set $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is finite

So this has a function $f$ which maps from a finite subset $S$ (of $\mathbb{R}$) to $\mathbb{R}$. This part, I honestly don't have any idea how to approach, and (as I'll mention below) I don't really know how the hint ties in.

- [Hint: use the fundamental theorem of algebra!]

I know that the premise of the fundamental theorem of algebra is that every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root. Since the question deals with mapping to $\mathbb{R}$ I'm not sure how this theorem necessarily relates. I'm assuming that the polynomials with complex roots are contained in set $S$, but I'm not sure how to use this theorem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the second part, you just found an infinite linearly independent set of $C[0,1]$, so it is infinite dimensional. For the third part, you can show indicator functions $1_x(y)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x=y\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ are linearly independent, so if $S$ is infinite then $F$ is infinite-dimensional. If $S$ is finite, then they moreover generate $F$ ($f=\sum f(x)1_x$), so $F$ is finite dimensional

Comment: It is also worth noting that the statement "more generally" is not entirely correct, since $C[0,1]$ is not of the form $\{f:S\to\mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro, I take "more generally" to mean that that $F$ contains only continuous functions. Then the hint about the fundamental theorem of algebra also makes more sense.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Very good point. In this case the solution I outlined does not work.

Comment: @MeesdeVries So are you thinking that the third part is disregarding the interval used in the previous two parts?

Comment: Well, disregarding... it is a more general case. First you proved specifically for the infinite set $[0,1]$ that the continuous functions on that set form an infinite-dimensional vector space. Now you are asked to prove it for all infinite sets $S$.